# Add an item in a Seq in scala

Tags: scala, seq

I am working with scala play 2 with slick. 
I have a Seq like

```
val customerList: Seq[CustomerDetail] = Seq(CustomerDetail("id", "status", "name"))
```

I want to add a CustomerDetail item in this customerList. How can I do this?
I already tried

```
customerList :+ CustomerDetail("1", "Active", "Shougat")
```

But this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things. When you use `:+`, the operation is *left associative*, meaning the element you're calling the method on should be on the left hand side.

Now, `Seq` (as used in your example) refers to `immutable.Seq`. When you append or prepend an element, it returns a *new sequence* containing the extra element, it doesn't add it to the existing sequence.

```
val newSeq = customerList :+ CustomerDetail("1", "Active", "Shougat")
```

But appending an element means traversing the entire list in order to add an item, consider prepending:

```
val newSeq = CustomerDetail("1", "Active", "Shougat") +: customerList
```

A simplified example:

```
scala> val original = Seq(1,2,3,4)
original: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val newSeq = 0 +: original
newSeq: Seq[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: you say `Seq` is immutable (and it probably is) but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: The concrete implementation may not be mutable, true. But the abstraction on `Seq` itself only exposes immutable properties.

Comment: Which one? `scala.collection.mutable.Seq` definitely exposes mutable properties.

Comment: The immutable one I and the OP are using in this example.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth pointing out that while the `Seq` append item operator, `:+`, is *left associative*, the prepend operator, `+:`, is *right associative*.

So if you have a `Seq` collection with `List` elements:

```
scala> val SeqOfLists: Seq[List[String]] = Seq(List("foo", "bar"))
SeqOfLists: Seq[List[String]] = List(List(foo, bar))
```

and you want to add another "elem" to the Seq, appending is done this way:

```
scala> SeqOfLists :+ List("foo2", "bar2")
res0: Seq[List[String]] = List(List(foo, bar), List(foo2, bar2))
```

and prepending is done this way:

```
scala> List("foo2", "bar2") +: SeqOfLists
res1: Seq[List[String]] = List(List(foo2, bar2), List(foo, bar))
```

as described in the [API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Seq):

> A mnemonic for +: vs. :+ is: the COLon goes on the COLlection side.

Neglecting this when handling collections of collections can lead to unexpected results, i.e.:

```
scala> SeqOfLists +: List("foo2", "bar2")
res2: List[Object] = List(List(List(foo, bar)), foo2, bar2)
```

Comment: @Yuval I can't comment yet on your post, so I am adding comment here. At time of writing this your append and prepend examples have `customerList` on the wrong side of the `:` (Colon). The collection being added to should be on the colon side of the operator.